# Rails dynamic form issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a dynamic form based off http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2.

I have this link:
views/shared/_new_field.html.erb

```
<%= link_to_add_fields "Add Field", f, :application_fields, @current_section.id %>
```

Which is here:
helpers/application_helper.rb

```
# Generates a link_to add a new application field.
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association, section_id) 
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
        render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder) 
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields buttonS bBlue button", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", ""), section_id: section_id})
end
```

Which generates a form that when I fill out the fields and submit, it generates the params hash:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Cl8XQNZeKRMtpdE0MLNhEX3by67bEcntjaAxygsduyo=", "application"=>{"application_fields_attributes"=>{"1380071101589"=>{"field_name"=>"RRR", "field_type"=>"textfield", "required"=>"0", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create", "id"=>"1", "section_id"=>"2"}
```

And this is the controller method:

```
...
@application = current_company.applications.find(params[:id])
@application.update_attributes(params[:application])

if @application.update_attributes(params[:application])
...
```

**The Problem**

With my current controller method, it's not saving the `section_id` to the `ApplicationField` row.

```
I also tried this in my controller method:
...
@application = current_company.applications.find(params[:id])
@application.assign_attributes(params[:application])
@application.section_id = params[:section_id]

if @application.save
...
```

but that generates the error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `section_id=' for #<Application:0x007f8300138ca8>
```

I'm at a loss for what i need to do to get the section id to save to the ApplicationField row.

**Models For Reference**

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
    has_many :application_fields, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :application_fields, :allow_destroy => true
    attr_accessible :application_name, :company_id, :application_fields_attributes
end

class ApplicationField < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :application
    has_many :application_fields_values, :dependent => :destroy
    attr_accessible :field_name, :field_type, :xposition, :yposition, :required, :application_id, :template_id, :options, :section_id 
end
```

Output of field.inspect in helper method:

```
"<div class=\"application_field formRow add_fields_form\" id=\"new_application_field\" remote=\"true\">\n    \n    <div class=\"formRow\">\n\t    <label for=\"application_application_fields_attributes_70100276854720_field_name\">Field name</label>\n\t    <input id=\"application_application_fields_attributes_70100276854720_field_name\" name=\"application[application_fields_attributes][70100276854720][field_name]\" size=\"30\" type=\"text\" />\n\t</div>\n    \n    <div class=\"formRow\">\n\t    <label for=\"application_application_fields_attributes_70100276854720_field_type\">Field type</label>\n\t    <select class=\"select\" id=\"field_type_dropdown\" name=\"application[application_fields_attributes][70100276854720][field_type]\"><option value=\"textfield\">Textfield</option>\n<option value=\"checkbox\">Checkbox</option>\n<option value=\"dropdown\">Dropdown</option>\n<option value=\"biglabel\">Big Label</option>\n<option value=\"smalllabel\">Small Label</option></select>\n\t</div>\n    \n    <div class=\"formRow\">\n\t    <input name=\"application[application_fields_attributes][70100276854720][required]\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"0\" /><input class=\"check\" id=\"application_application_fields_attributes_70100276854720_required\" name=\"application[application_fields_attributes][70100276854720][required]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"1\" />\n\t    <label for=\"application_application_fields_attributes_70100276854720_required\">Required</label>\n\t</div>\n    \n    <!-- Need to store the hidden field _destroy here so we can access it via jQuery -->\n    <input id=\"application_application_fields_attributes_70100276854720__destroy\" name=\"application[application_fields_attributes][70100276854720][_destroy]\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"false\" />\n    \n    <div class=\"grid1\" align=\"center\">\n        \n    </div>\n    \n    <div id=\"new_field_buttons\" class=\"formRow\">\n        <div id=\"new_field_buttons\" class=\"fluid sideWidget\">\n            <div class=\"grid6\">\n                <input class=\"buttonS bBlue\" name=\"commit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Create\" />\n            </div>\n            <div class=\"grid6\">\n                <input id=\"cancel_new_field\" class=\"buttonS bRed\" type=\"button\" value=\"Cancel\">\n            </div>\n        </div>\n    </div>\n    <div class=\"clear\"></div>\n</div>\n"
ributes][70100276854720][_destroy]\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"false\" />\n    \n    <div class=\"grid1\" align=\"center\">\n        \n    </div>\n    \n    <div id=\"new_field_buttons\" class=\"formRow\">\n        <div id=\"new_field_buttons\" class=\"fluid sideWidget\">\n            <div class=\"grid6\">\n                <input class=\"buttonS bBlue\" name=\"commit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Create\" />\n            </div>\n            <div class=\"grid6\">\n                <input id=\"cancel_new_field\" class=\"buttonS bRed\" type=\"button\" value=\"Cancel\">\n            </div>\n        </div>\n    </div>\n    <div class=\"clear\"></div>\n</div>\n"
             <input class=\"buttonS bBlue\" name=\"commit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Create\" />\n            </div>\n            <div class=\"grid6\">\n                <input id=\"cancel_new_field\" class=\"buttonS bRed\" type=\"button\" value=\"Cancel\">\n            </div>\n        </div>\n    </div>\n    <div class=\"clear\"></div>\n</div>\n"
div class=\"clear\"></div>\n</div>\n"
```

Comment: Just a guess without digging too deep. It appears that `section_id` is in the base params hash & not part of the `application_fields_attributes` hash. So, either add it to the `fields` block in the helper or access it as `params[:section_id]` in the controller. The error is saying essentially that application does not have that method/field.

Comment: I tried to add it to the controller and use assign_attributes and then add it manually as you can see in my second controller snippet, but it was saving it to the `Application` rather than the `ApplicationField`. Can you either elaborate on how to add it to the `fields` block or help me with how to fix my second controller snippet to add it to the `ApplicationField`?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to assign `ApplicationField` attributes to an `Application` object in the controller. The second last line of the controller, you have `@application.section_id = ...`, but according to your model that class of object doesn't contain that method. Could that be it?

Comment: @Teeg Yes that is the reason why my second version of my controller method does not work, but I don't understand how `@application.update_attributes(params[:application])` creates an `ApplicationField` record so I don't know how to add `params[:section_id]` to it.

Comment: Maybe try `fields[:section_id] = section_id` right after the block & before the `link_to` call in the helper?

Comment: Yes, what Brian said. To answer your question to me, you have that `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in `Application` which means an `ApplicationField` is implicitly created and properly associated when you pass a properly structured hash when creating an `Application` object. In your case, after the `Application` object is created, you'll have one or more associated `ApplicationField` objects as well. Iterating through each of those would be a pain, and needless, which is why Brian's suggestion makes sense.

Comment: @Brian's suggestion gives the error: `Can't convert Symbol into Integer`.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't sure what type of object fields_for returned.  Can you do an inspect or something on that object to see what it looks like & post it? My guess it wasn't a simple hash as I expected.

Comment: I added the output of fields.inspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the `section_id` to the `link_to` method, try passing it as a variable to the `render` method like so:

```
render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder, section_id: section_id)
```

This way you can just insert a hidden field in your application_field_fields partial that adds the `section_id` to the form data that is posted to your controller:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :section_id, :value => section_id %>
```